# Select mySQL data with help of other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I'm currently working on a message board which only displays data if values in another table are set.

My 2 tables look like this:

```
tbsubscribers:
-subID (int)
-msg1 (tinyint)
-msg2 (tinyint)
-msg3 (tinyint)
-email (varchar)

tbmessage
-id (int)
-name (varchar)
-mitteilung (varchar)
-sender (varchar)
-datum (datetime)
```

The actual messages are in the tbmessage table and to check which messages the user wants to see there is the tbsubscribers table.

Now, I want to display the messages. So if a user subscribed to `msg1` and `msg2` (so the value of both are 1) it should select all the data from tbmessage which has the name `'msg1'` and `'msg2'`.

I know how to work with select in mysql but don't know how I could select multiple tables, and especially in this case I'm kind of confused how I would do this.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple join should work:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbsubscribers` s
RIGHT JOIN `tbmessage` tb ON (
  CASE WHEN msg1 = 1 THEN name = 'msg1' END OR
  CASE WHEN msg2 = 1 THEN name = 'msg2' END OR
  CASE WHEN msg3 = 1 THEN name = 'msg3' END
)
```

I created a [sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/112d4/12), which should demonstrate the functionality you're looking for.

I'm going to make some edits to clarify how you should do this, using both the query above, and another query if need be.

There are a few ways you can do this. Way #1:

```
<?php

/*
 * If you already have username (email) in session,
 * then you can do this:
 */

$query = "SELECT m.* FROM `tbsubscribers` s
RIGHT JOIN `tbmessage` m ON (
  CASE WHEN msg1 = 1 THEN name = 'msg1' END OR
  CASE WHEN msg2 = 1 THEN name = 'msg2' END OR
  CASE WHEN msg3 = 1 THEN name = 'msg3' END
)
WHERE email = " . my_escape_string_function($_SESSION['username']);

/*
 * If tbsubscribers has a '1' in msg1, then all msg1's are grabbed.
 * If tbsubscribers has a '2' in msg2, then all msg2's are grabbed...etc
 */

//Set $rows equal to the result

return $rows;

?>
```

Way #2:

```
<?php

/*
 * If you already have username (email) in session,
 * then you can do this:
 */

$query = "SELECT * FROM `tbsubscribers` s
WHERE email = " . my_escape_string_function($_SESSION['username']);

/*
 * Run this query, and fetch the entire userrow, and put into $user
 * An alternative could be to just store the entire user array into
 * $_SESSION, as you wont have to query the database twice.
 */

$tofetch = array();

for ( $i=1; $i<=3; $i++ )
{
    //Let's check msg1, msg2, msg3
    if ( $user['msg' . $i] )
    {
        $tofetch[] = "name = 'msg" . $i . "'";
    }
}

/*
 * If tbsubscribers has a '1' in msg1, and a '1' in msg2 then the array
 * will look like this:
 * array(
 * 0 => "name = 'msg1'"
 * 1 => "name = 'msg2'"
 * )
 */

//Throw an exception if all 'msg1', 'msg2', and 'msg3' are all 0 (Otherwise the query will fail)
if ( empty($tofetch) ) {
    throw new Exception("You're not subscribed to any messages.");
}

/*
 * Now it's a simple query. $tofetch will be imploded, to form a nice
 * where statement. Using the example above, it will look like:
 * name = 'msg1' OR name = 'msg2'
 */
$query = "SELECT *
FROM `tbmessage`
WHERE " . implode(' OR ', $tofetch);

//Set $rows equal to the result

return $rows;
```

Comment: And outputting data would work the same with the other table? echo $row["name"];

Comment: I'm still fixing it up a bit: I assume msg1 is like a `0` or a `1`, and if it's `1`, you want it to grab everything from the other table where `name = 'msg1'` correct? Is there anything else linking the two tables together?

Comment: no this is everything. Exactly, if msg1 = 1 show everything from that table

Comment: But in your question, you said if `msg1 = 1`, you want to get all the data from tbmessage which has the name `'msg1'`.

Comment: I don't quite understand it
In the end I want to only display the messages which the user has subscribed to, so the ones with value = 1.

Comment: You have to help me out here. You're not giving me much to go on. I gave you a two example queries which should retrieve the messages that a specific user is subscribed to. Query 1 pulls all `msg1`'s. Query 2 pulls all `msg1`'s and `msg2`'s (Based on the sample data I provided), which should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I'm going to explain a little bit further
So i'm storing a session:$user = $_SESSION['username'];
And this username is an email which is stored in email in tbsubscribers
I already made a script where the user can check 3 different checkboxes and when said checkbox is checked it writes a 1 in the tbsubscribers (msg1, msg2, msg3) where this email is.
Now, the diffferent messages jpwever come from tbmessage.
So, I wanna check which messages (msg1, msg2 or msg3) the user checked and output ONLY the ones the user checked.
For each message there is a value in tbmessage. I hope you understand.

Comment: I've added even more clarification. I hope this helps. Please remember to vote up/mark as the answer if this works for you.

Comment: I understand what you mean now!

Comment: Only problem is I get errors. Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Sie haben bisher keine Foren abonniert.' in C:\Users\Jeremy\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\bootstrap\employapp_v1.0\pages\index.php:542 Stack trace: #0 {main}

Comment: it means "you have not subscribed to any messages yet"

Comment: I assume you're using my code in #2. You need to take a look at try {} catch {} blocks in php: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php. If you're new at PHP, just replace the `throw new Exception` line I have with some other form of showing the user they haven't subscribed to any messages.

Comment: okay thanks, I just did an echo output! Now for some reason I don't get any output even if all the msg's are set to 1. It just displays the echo message I put into if ( empty($tofetch) .
I put the user row into a variable like this $user= mysql_fetch_row($query);

Do I need to change $tofetch = array();?

Comment: echo out `$query` right below, and see what it's generating. Go into your MySQL editor (Like phpmyadmin), and paste it into the SQL tab and make sure it works. You can also use `mysql_error` to find out why it's not returning any rows.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: rows is what I get in php. the "echo $query" doesn't output anything at all. When I put the query into phpmyadmin it works perfectly.

Comment: Not trying to be rude here: But you really need to attempt to do some of this on your own. I've literally handed you the solution, and you are most likely not going to get someone as helpful as me in the future. A lot of this is problem solving, going to google and searching when you encounter an error. Some of this is trial and error. Stackoverflow is really not intended as a "Here's my problem, do it for me" site. We can assist, but you have to help yourself before we can help you. That being said: http://pastebin.com/Ye79HrTf